# can't update attribute and change the TimeZone for other attribute in Breeze

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, hottowel

While activating my Edit view page, I am trying to get the entities from different tables using foreign keys, Which I am getting but I think its not the correct way of fetching and updating the entities, which is not saving the updated attribute "modification_date" and another problem which I am facing is time issue, as I have one attribute "startDate" which is datetime type, So when I am hosted my application to some VM then its showing the time which is +5:30 more from the original value because the database is storing the value in GMT +00:00. How can I solve this problem? 
My question is:

> 1. Why "modification_date" is not saving current date, whenever entity is updated.

```
 <input data-bind="value: modificationDate = $root.md, visible: false"
>
```

Javascript

```
vm.md = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var y = new Date();// should assign current to modification date but its not persisting the changes to database.
        return y;
        }, vm);
```

> 2. How can I show the correct time which is in GMT +00:00 to client side when my current is GMT +5:30. While editing and fetching the data from SqlServer.
> 3. Please comment how we use the navigation key to access the other table as what I am doing is getting a 'Job' observable and in that different attributes are there and another table is 'job_Schedule', so how should I access the property startDate which is under 'job_Schedule' table. As currently I am accessing is like `job_Schedule._latestValue[0].startDate` which is probably not the right way to fetch the entity.

[image]

Here is piece of my code:

```
 <div data-bind="with: job">
<label>Start Date :</label>
                        <input data-bind="kendoDateTimePicker: $root.temp3" />
                        <input data-bind="value: job_Schedule._latestValue[0].startDate = $root.tempSD1, visible: false" />
     <input data-bind="value: modificationDate = $root.md, visible: false" >
//I kept visible: false because modified date should be updated automatically
// some more attributes................
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
    vm.md = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var y = new Date();// should assign current to modification date but its not persisting the changes to database.
    return y;
    }, vm);

vm.tempSD = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var y = ko.unwrap(this.tempx());// tempx containing the current value of startDate
    if (y === null || y === '""') { y = new Date(); }
    y = new Date(y);
    var utc = y.getTime() + (y.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    temp3(new Date(utc));
    return new Date(utc);
}, vm);

vm.tempSD1 = ko.computed(function () {
    var y = vm.temp3();
    if (y === null || y === '""') {y = new Date();}
    y = new Date(y);
    var utc = y.getTime() - (y.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    return new Date(utc);
},vm);
```

Comment: What is modificationDate?  Why are you trying to set it in a binding expression instead of in JavaScript?

Comment: How can I achieve in javaScript then ? as "modificationDate" is a column from database.

Comment: `vm.job.modificationDate(new Date());` assuming vm.job is a Breeze entity that has a `modificationDate` property.

Comment: No we can't do it that way I already tried that, it will show error `Failed to load routed module (viewmodels/jobedit). Details: vm.job.modificationDate is not a function`

Comment: ah, I see that vm.job is an observable.  So it would be `vm.job().modificationDate(new Date());`

Comment: Details: Cannot read property 'modificationDate' of undefined

Comment: I found a way by updating the bindings `<input data-bind="value: $data.modificationDate(new Date()), visible: false" >`

Comment: My previous comments assumed that your vm had a `job` property that contained the `job` entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates manipulation is a long-standing challenge for everyone in every technology.

Timezone manipulation is particularly tricky, especially when the client and server are in different time zones.

This can be less of a problem when you can ensure that all dates are created and stored in [UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). I don't think you want to be relying exclusively upon calls to `new Date()`.

I recommend looking into the [momentjs date/time library](http://momentjs.com/).

I don't know how to address your question about navigating to a related entity as you have not provided any information about the entity types involved or their relationships. Is this a separate question? Or is there a connection between your navigation property and your date issue?

Comment: Thanks Ward, let me re-frame the question again, What I want to know that the entities I am getting are from 2 tables 'Job_Details' and 'Job_Schedule' where Job_Schedule is having a foreign key 'JobID' and basis on that I am populating the data from both the tables into 'job' observable and this observable is containing everything I need. Now question is `Am I using correct syntax to access the 'job_Schedule' entities?`, as I am accessing it in my view like `job_Schedule._latestValue[0].startDate`.

Comment: If there is another best way I am ready to follow that. for more reference I am posting image of observable so that u ll get a clear picture of the structure of my data which is populating into my observable.

Comment: Please check I updated my post with the image of my job Observable